# Broken Linux kernel <linux/...> includes on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, linux-kernel-headers

I'm trying to write a kernel module in VS Code on Ubuntu 20.04

The problem is that my includes seem to be completely broken.

Firstly, I have no `<linux/uaccess.h>` or `<asm/uaccess.h>` headers. Secondly, I have put many includes on top of my file like:

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
```

However, no definitions for kernel stuff like `printk()` are found. Macros like `bool` or `NULL` are also not defined in my `linux/types.h`.

I tried `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic`.

Here's my `linux/module.h`:

```c
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0 WITH Linux-syscall-note */
#ifndef _LINUX_MODULE_H
#define _LINUX_MODULE_H

/* Flags for sys_finit_module: */
#define MODULE_INIT_IGNORE_MODVERSIONS  1
#define MODULE_INIT_IGNORE_VERMAGIC 2

#endif /* _LINUX_MODULE_H */
```

My `linux/kernel.h`:

```c
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0 WITH Linux-syscall-note */
#ifndef _LINUX_KERNEL_H
#define _LINUX_KERNEL_H

#include <linux/sysinfo.h>
#include <linux/const.h>

#endif /* _LINUX_KERNEL_H */
```

Comment: 1. You need to install the kernel source. 2. You need to set up the include path within vscode. 3. Generally the include path is for the current kernel & set to `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/source/include/` at least.

Comment: What do you mean by installing kernel source? I have linux kernel installed since I have Ubuntu. And for headers I did `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic`

Comment: Building kernel modules requires either using the kernel Makefile or reproducing all of its features.

Comment: I understand that if I want to build the module, I need the a specific Makefile. The errors I get arise before the build. I simply don't see any declarations of the functions I'm using inside the headers. And I don't have a header <linux/uaccess.h> at all

Comment: Have you stumbled upon e.g.  [this](https://sysprog21.github.io/lkmpg/#headers) and done the equivalent steps required in VS Code?

Comment: Yes, I have installed the headers using those commands

Comment: It smells like you are trying to compile Linux kernel module by direct calling the compiler. This doesn't work: You need to use a Makefile specifically created for building a kernel module. If I am wrong and you have already use such Makefile, then add it to the **question post**. In the current form of your question it is unclear what do you actually are doing.

Comment: I have run into problems even before trying to compile: 1) I simply do not have a header <linux/uaccess.h>. 2) my headers do not contain almost anything the're supposed to contain. Compare my header `linux/module.h` with the same header  [on github](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/module.h)

Comment: `However, no definitions for kernel stuff like` How do you know? Please post the exact compilation command you are using with the exact full verbatim compiler messages you are getting. `Compare my header` That's simple - you are looking at the wrong file. Once again - "you need to use a makefile specifically created for building kernel module". Are you using it? No, it's not /usr/include/linux/kernel.h, and that file is also on github in uapi https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/module.h . You have to use kernel headers, not uapi, for building kernel.

Comment: Overall, consider re-reading the introduction to building kernel modules that you are following.  From my short google search, this one https://medium.com/dvt-engineering/how-to-write-your-first-linux-kernel-module-cf284408beeb "looks" ok. See the makefile included in that link. `I have run into problems even before trying to compile` I would suggest to consider ignoring these problems and start compiling. What are these problems? Were you able to create files? What does the compilation results when you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These headers are kernel-space headers, which means they cannot be found within the user-space headers (`/usr/include/linux`). In my Fedora machine, this is how I diagnose it.

#### 1. Make sure those headers exist

I use a simple `find /usr -name uaccess.h 2>/dev/null` to list all files. The result might look like below:

```
/usr/src/kernels/6.6.4-200.fc39.x86_64/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h
/usr/src/kernels/6.6.4-200.fc39.x86_64/include/asm-generic/uaccess.h
/usr/src/kernels/6.6.4-200.fc39.x86_64/include/linux/uaccess.h
/usr/src/kernels/6.6.6-200.fc39.x86_64/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h
/usr/src/kernels/6.6.6-200.fc39.x86_64/include/asm-generic/uaccess.h
/usr/src/kernels/6.6.6-200.fc39.x86_64/include/linux/uaccess.h
/usr/src/kernels/6.6.7-200.fc39.x86_64/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h
/usr/src/kernels/6.6.7-200.fc39.x86_64/include/asm-generic/uaccess.h
/usr/src/kernels/6.6.7-200.fc39.x86_64/include/linux/uaccess.h
```

#### 2. How to use those kernel headers

An intuitive way to use those headers is to include them all when compiling. However, this is error-prone due to linking issues.

A (somewhat) standard way is to define it as module.

Source code:

```c
// printk-example.c

#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Your Name");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A simple kernel module with printk");

static int __init hello_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello, this is your kernel module!\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye, exiting your kernel module!\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

Makefile:

```
obj-m += printk-example.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

You might search for the rest on running kernel modules for your machine.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you. The problem I described in the question indeed was due to include path errors. But I ran into another problem I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77716832/vs-code-include-path-for-kernel-development-behaves-weirdly)